# How to use Compass Animation for Compass SCSS framework?

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I am trying to use [compass animation](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animation), but it doesn't seem to work.

Here are how my files are set up:

**Config.rb**

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
require 'animation'
```

**Screen.scss**

```
@import "compass";
@import "compass/reset";
@import "animation";
@import "animation/animate";
@import "animation/animate/classes";


.widget:hover {
    @include animation(flipOutY);
    background:pink;
}

body {
    background:red;
}
```

**Index.html**

```
<a href="#" class="widget">Click Me</a>
```

This is the output of my css:

```
@-moz-keyframes flipOutY {
  /* line 79, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  0% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1; }

  /* line 83, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  100% {
    -moz-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0; } }

@-webkit-keyframes flipOutY {
  /* line 79, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1; }

  /* line 83, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0; } }

@-o-keyframes flipOutY {
  /* line 79, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  0% {
    -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1; }

  /* line 83, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  100% {
    -o-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0; } }

@-ms-keyframes flipOutY {
  /* line 79, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  0% {
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1; }

  /* line 83, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  100% {
    -ms-transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0; } }

@keyframes flipOutY {
  /* line 79, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  0% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(0deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
    opacity: 1; }

  /* line 83, ../../../../../../../../Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/animation-0.1.alpha.3/stylesheets/animation/animate/_flippers.scss */
  100% {
    transform: perspective(400px) rotateY(90deg);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0);
    opacity: 0; } }

.widget:hover {
-webkit-animation: flipOutY;
-moz-animation: flipOutY;
-ms-animation: flipOutY;
-o-animation: flipOutY;
animation: flipOutY;
background: pink;
}
```

However, it doesn't seem to be working. Could someone explain what I am doing wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work how?  The generated CSS is incorrect?

Comment: @cimmanon. When I load up the page and hover over the element, nothing happens. I have tried all the browsers, but nothing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a duration is required in order for this to work. That's a mistake in the README.

(You should also note that Compass Animation isn't really being maintained any longer - as it is moving into the Compass Core for 0.13 release. I recommend using the master branch of Compass, and [Compass-Animate](https://github.com/ericam/compass-animate) instead. Those are better maintained.)

Comment: How do you use the duration for a built in animation. I've read around by can't seem to work it out. Also, is Compass 0.13 safe to use, as its still in Alpha? If I switch over, will I have to make lots of changes to make my files work? Are there any resources that explain more about it. I've searched around but not really found anything. Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: The built-in animations are simply named keyframe sets, and take duration arguments the same as any other animation you create: `@include animation(flipOutY 300ms);` or `animation-name(flipOutY); animation-duration(300ms);`. 0.13 alpha is actually a bit out of date, so unless you're willing to use the master branch directly, I may have spoke too soon. :) Sorry. If compass-animations is working, stick with that till 0.13 gets an update.

Comment: when the Compass 0.13 will coming ?

Comment: There is no set date. Hopefully soon.

Comment: Dear @EricMeyer, will the animate mixins be present by default in compass, or will I have to separately install the compass-animate plugin? (I'm asking this because the readme on both the repos: animation and animate are somewhat muddled and I can't make enough sense out of them)

Also, any clue as to when compass 0.13 will be coming out? Just asking, no pressure :)

Comment: The animate mixins will not be part of Compass - you'll want to use compass-animate. I'm not sure when 0.13 will land.

Comment: **Maybe add a disclaimer that you are the owner of compass-animate???** Might be a good idea.

Comment: More important disclaimer: both Compass and Compass-Animate are old, end-of-life, and unmaintained.